# NGINX http2 push for a VUE SPA

Tags: nginx, vuejs2, http2, nginx-config

I would like to use the http2 server push in publishing a VUE SPA.
I found [this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-13-9-http2-server-push/) interesting article and tried to use: `http2_push_preload on`, in publishing the VUE SPA.

```
location / { 
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404; 
http2_push_preload on; 
}
```

But it does not work, as using
`nghttp -ans https://mysite/index.html`
returns a response where none of the resources listed is annotated with an asterisk.

What it was wrong?

Comment: Have you added preload link headers? `http2_push_preload on` just enables another way to preload the files. You still need to actually tell Nginx which files you want to push.

Comment: No, how I can add preload link headers? Could you provide me an example?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-13-9-http2-server-push/#automatic-push

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable http2

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
}
```

Note that accepting HTTP/2 connections over TLS requires the “Application-Layer Protocol Negotiation” (ALPN) TLS extension support, which is available only since OpenSSL version 1.0.2. Using the “Next Protocol Negotiation” (NPN) TLS extension for this purpose (available since OpenSSL version 1.0.1) is not guaranteed to work.